# Wordpress links widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a link in my wp website. Which looks like

```
<a class="more-video-link" href="">Some external website<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I'd like to be able to edit href of this link using admin panel.

so i need something like

```
<a class="more-video-link" href="{php variable}">Some external website<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [metabox](https://docs.metabox.io/)
which is a plugin you can use to speed up the process of creating meta boxes and custom fields.

- Go to [Online Generator](https://metabox.io/online-generator/)
- Fill in all the info of meta boxes and custom fields
- Click button Generate Code to get the code
- Copy the code and paste into your theme’s functions.php

after that you Display field values with the function rwmb_meta. It takes the field ID and returns the field value. it should be something like this:

```
$value = rwmb_meta( 'name' );

<a class="more-video-link" href="<?php echo $value; ?>">Some external website<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```